# Developing a recursive/hierarchy query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need your help with this query I can't solve.
Here's the thing, let's say I have a table like this:

```
Father | Son
1      |   2
1      |   3
1      |   4
3      |   5
3      |   6
2      |   7
4      |   8
5      |   9
6      |   10
```

So as you can see the table represents a father-son relationship, I need to find all the sons (and the sons of the sons) of one father, for example if Im looking for the sons of number 1 we will get a table like this

```
Father | son
1      |   2
1      |   3
1      |   4
1      |   5
1      |   6
1      |   7
1      |   8
1      |   9
1      |   10
```

If I'm lookeing for the sons of the number 3 we will get:

```
Father | son
3      |   5
3      |   6
3      |   9
3      |   10
```

okay I think you understood my point. The next problem is that I have to do it for each father in the table. So at the end,  the table will be as follows:

```
Father | son
1      |   2
1      |   3
1      |   4
1      |   5
1      |   6
1      |   7
1      |   8
1      |   9
1      |   10
3      |   5
3      |   6
3      |   9
3      |   10
2      |   7
4      |   8
5      |   9
6      |   10
```

is pretty similar to go over a tree.
I have been trying to figure out this query for a while with not success. I did a code like this

```
WITH  son
        AS (
              -- in 
            SELECT  FK_CC_B
            FROM    PG_Rols_CC  
            WHERE   FK_CC_A = @idCC
            UNION ALL
              --recur
            SELECT  t.FK_CC_B
            FROM     PG_Rols_CC AS t
                    JOIN hijos AS a
                      ON t.FK_CC_A = a.FK_CC_B
           )
insert into @TableSons (idSon) SELECT * FROM son
```

But it doesn't works for each father at the same time and the resulting table is a little bit different, it only has the son ID. Example

```
son
3
4
5
6
7
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: cannot you select * and order by father?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get the descendents of all fathers, you need to get rid of the `WHERE` clause in the first part of your Common Table Expression (CTE).

If you want to output two columns (Father and Descendent), you need to add these columns to both parts of the CTE.

Like this:

```
WITH Son
AS
(
    SELECT
        FK_CC_A AS Father,
        FK_CC_B AS Son
    FROM
        PG_Rols_CC
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        f.Father,
        s.FK_CC_B AS Son
    FROM
        Son f
        INNER JOIN PG_Rols_CC s ON f.Son = s.FK_CC_A
)

SELECT * FROM Son
```

Comment: Yep, that did the query. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You need to refer to the 'Anchor' part from the 'recursive' member...

Does something like this work:

```
WITH  son
        AS (
              -- in 
            SELECT  @Father, Son
            FROM    PG_Rols_CC  
            WHERE   FK_CC_A = @Father
            UNION ALL
              --recur
            SELECT  @Father, Son
            FROM     PG_Rols_CC AS t
                    JOIN son AS s
                      ON s.FK_CC_A = t.FK_CC_B
           )
SELECT * FROM son
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Your code fixes the problem with getting the father and son code, but It doesn't do it for each father, just for @father

Comment: Just remove the WHERE clause from the anchor member.. and then replace the @Father in the select list of both the anchore member and the recursive member to be the column name of the father, whatever that is.

Comment: No actually you'd need to include the father in the recursive member from the anchor member like this: `Select s.FK_CC_A, t.FK_CC_B` or whatever is the correct columns?