# Recursive data modeling and querying?

Tags: sql, recursion, many-to-many, relational-database, data-modeling

I have an object in my data model like so:

```
// A word in the English language.
public class Word {
    private Long id;                 // Ex: 35
    private String text;             // Ex: "catlike"
    private Integer length;          // Ex: 7
    private String definition;       // Ex: "resembling a cat; stealthy"
    private List<Word> synonyms;     // Ex: "quick", "nimble"
    private List<Word> antonyms;     // Ex: "sluggish", "slow"

    // Getters, setters, ctors, etc. omitted for brevity; this is a simple POJO/bean
}
```

As you can see, it contains 2 "recursive" lists of other words (synonyms and antonyms). A `Word` has a many-to-many relationship with both it's synonyms and it's antonyms. For instance: a synonym for "*cat-like*" might be "*quick*", but "*quick*" is also a synonym for "*fast*", etc.

My *plan* is to model `Word`s in the database with the use of 3 different tables: 1 main `words` table, and 2 crosswalk/join tables:

- `words`
- `synonyms` (crosswalk)
- `antonyms` (crosswalk)

The tables and their fields:

```
[words]
    id            PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT
    text          VARCHAR
    length        INTEGER
    definition    VARCHAR

[synonyms]
    id            PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT
    word_1_id     FOREIGN KEY (words)
    word_2_id     FOREIGN KEY (words)

[antonyms]
    id            PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT
    word_1_id     FOREIGN KEY (words)
    word_2_id     FOREIGN KEY (words)
```

So my *thinking* here is, if I wanted to query for any word that had "*metal*" in its description, or has any synonyms that have "*metal*" in them, my query might look like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    words w
INNER JOIN
    synonyms s
ON
    w.id = s.word_1_id
WHERE
    w.definition LIKE '%metal%'
    OR
    ??? (synonym of w).definition LIKE '%metal%'
```

**Am I modelling this recrusive relationship correctly**?!? I feel like I'm either dead-on, or completely off-base and overlooking something glaringly obvious. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is this recursive? Are you looking for words that have other words in their synonym chain deeper than one? For example, are you looking for your query to return words such that one of the synonyms of their synonym synonyms has `'metal'` in it, or should only the immediate synonyms be examined?

Comment: Thanks @dasblinkenlight (+1) - I might be using *recursive* incorrectly here (in which case, please correct me!). But the important thing here is that I'm tryin to accomplish 2 things: (1) I want tables that correctly mode my Java POJO (where every `Word` can have 0+ `Word` synonyms and antonyms), and (2) I can query for any word that has "metal" in its definition, as well as any of its synonyms that also have "metal" in their descriptions. Thanks again!

Comment: You should realise that the synonyms and antonyms relations are **not** symmetric: there are situations where you cannot replace "quick" by "catlike" e.g in "quick service".

Comment: Good point @wildplasser (+1) - please see my comment under dasblinkenlight's response...I have the same question for you!

Comment: There is also the additional issue of `homonyms`, which might spoil your party.

Comment: Thanks again @wildplasser - I will handle `homonyms` by placing a UNIQUE-ness constraint on `word.text` and `word.type` (type is ADJECTIVE, NOUN, etc.). Therefore, I can insert both ("prune", NOUN) and ("prune", VERB) into the table, and they'd each have separate IDs to use in the synonyms/antonyms tables.

Comment: a UNIQUE constraint on {type,text} will not solve the homonyms problem. Take for instance the word "order" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want tables that correctly mode my Java POJO (where every Word can have 0+ Word synonyms and antonyms)

Your DB model is fine, it should be able to support your model on the Java side. Note that `synonyms` and `antonyms` are directional, so you should either add records for both directions, or treat a single record as bidirectional in your join conditions.

> I can query for any word that has "metal" in its definition, as well as any of its synonyms also have "metal" in their descriptions.

Your query does not need a join at the top, and can be completed by using an `EXISTS` operator, like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM words w
WHERE
    w.definition LIKE '%metal%'
    OR
    EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM words ww
        JOIN synonyms ss ON ww.id = ss.word_1_id
        WHERE ww.definition LIKE '%metal%'
    )
```

Note that this query will give you the word that fits the condition, not its synonyms/antonyms. These should be queried separately to complete the data needed for your Java representation. In order to complete this part of the query you may need to build a recursive query that gives you all words related to a given one through a set of many-to-many tables. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13593763/335858) for an example.

To treat your many-to-many tables symmetrically, change

```
ww.id = ss.word_1_id
```

condition to this:

```
ww.id = ss.word_1_id OR ww.id = ss.word_2_id
```

This would model the meaning "word W has a synonym Q, or is a synonym of Q".

Comment: Thanks again @dasblinkenlight (+1) - I guess I *do* want to make sure my relationships are properly directional since synonyms and anotnyms are not always symmetric, like you say. As another user pointed out, it may be fine to use "quick" in place of "catlike", but you might not always be able use "catlike" in place of "quick". So I'll re-phrase: is my data model correct for handling this asymmetric relationship between synonyms/antonyms? If not, how should it change, and how would your suggested query above (using `EXISTS`) change? Thanks again!

Comment: @TicketMonster The query assumes that the relations are not symmetric, i.e. the presence of a record `{word1_id, word2_id}` implies that `word2` is a synonym of `word1`, but it does not imply that `word1` is also a synonym of `word2`. Your data model is fine for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
SELECT
    *
FROM
    words w
WHERE
    w.definition LIKE '%metal%'
) UNION (
SELECT
    w1.*
FROM
    words w1,
    words w2,
    synonyms s
WHERE
    w1.id = s.word_1_id and
    w2.id = s.word_2_id and
    w2.definition LIKE '%metal%'
)
```

)